# How to plot the dataframes with Permutations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, permutation

I am not sure if my title is a precise title or not. If not, feel free to edit it!

Hi! I have three dataframes and want to plot it to scatter plots. But currently, I just write in three different plots and don't know how to write into one. To be more specific, according to the below codes, I want to do like this. `x[i], y[i]`, `y[i], z[i]`and `x[i], z[i]`are three choices, so i need to adjust the variable manually. Also, the kind is a list, contain three strings (`kind = ["food", "meat", "vege"]`) , and if kind1 and kind2 equal 0 and 1, it is for x and y; if kinds equal 0 and 2 respectively, it is for x and z; if kind1 and kind2 are 1 and 2, it's for y and z.

Here are some dataframes you can try.

```py
food = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
food_df = pd.DataFrame(data=food)

meat = {'col1': [3, 6], 'col2': [1, 2]}
meat_df = pd.DataFrame(data=meat)

vege = {'col1': [5, 9], 'col2': [0, 3]}
vege_df = pd.DataFrame(data=vege)
```

Here is my current codes

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

kind = ["fooood", "meats", "vegea"]
features = ["Attack", "Volume"]
kind1 = 1
kind2 = 2
col = ["dd", "aa"]
def plot_scatter(feature):
    ind = features.index(feature)
    x = food_df.iloc[ind]
    y = meat_df.iloc[ind]
    z = vege_df.iloc[ind]
    for i, c in enumerate(np.unique(col)):
        plt.scatter(y[i], z[i], c = "b")
    for i, txt in enumerate(col):
        ax.annotate(txt, (y[i], z[i]), xytext=(y[i]+0.0001, z[i]+0.0001), size = 12)

    plt.xlabel(kind[kind1], size = 15)
    plt.ylabel(kind[kind2], size = 15)
    plt.title(f"{feature}")

plot_scatter("Attack")
plot_scatter("Volume")
```

I appreciate it!!!!!!!!

Comment: what is `features`?

Comment: `makers` is also undefined. Even after removing it, the code runs with an error. What is your exact issue? Do you have an error or are you looking for another way? You need to be specific.

Comment: @mozway Oh, sorry!! I edited again! Hope this time can work for u

Comment: OK, now it works. This gives me a [single graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEf82.png), is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's right. okay, let me type again what i wrote above.
```x[i], y[i]```, ```y[i], z[i]```and ```x[i], z[i]```are three choices, each combination I want to get the result. But i need to adjust the variable manually.
This is the first one I hope it could do automatically.

Comment: Also, the kind is a list, containing three strings (```kind = ["food", "meat", "vege"]```) , and if kind1 and kind2 equal 0 and 1, it is for x and y; if kinds equal 0 and 2 respectively, it is for x and z; if kind1 and kind2 are 1 and 2, it's for y and z. 
This one I also did manually, but I hope to do in a range or even function or sth i don't need to adjust the number every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:

After reading the dependency of `kind1` and `kind2` on the choice of `x, y and z`, I think this is better suited:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

food = {"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4]}
food_df = pd.DataFrame(data=food)

meat = {"col1": [3, 6], "col2": [1, 2]}
meat_df = pd.DataFrame(data=meat)

vege = {"col1": [5, 9], "col2": [0, 3]}
vege_df = pd.DataFrame(data=vege)
# Here is my current codes

kind = ["fooood", "meats", "vegea"]
features = ["Attack", "Volume"]
col = ["dd", "aa"]


def plot_scatter(feature):
    ind = features.index(feature)
    x = food_df.iloc[ind]
    y = meat_df.iloc[ind]
    z = vege_df.iloc[ind]
    combinations = ((0, 1, x, y), (0, 2, x, z), (1, 2, y, z))

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 10))

    for idx, (kind1, kind2, col1, col2) in enumerate(combinations):
        ax = axes[idx]

        for i, c in enumerate(np.unique(col)):
            ax.scatter(col1, col2, c="b")

        for i, txt in enumerate(col):
            ax.annotate(
                txt,
                (col1[i], col2[i]),
                xytext=(col1[i] + 0.0001, col2[i] + 0.0001),
                size=12,
            )

        ax.set_xlabel(kind[kind1], size=15)
        ax.set_ylabel(kind[kind2], size=15)
        ax.set_title(f"{feature}")

    return fig, axes


fig_attack, axes_attack = plot_scatter("Attack")
fig_volume, axes_volume = plot_scatter("Volume")
plt.show()
fig_attack.savefig("test_attack.png")
fig_volume.savefig("test_volume.png")
```

Result:

[image: test_volume.png]
[image: test_attack]

#### Original answer

IIUC, you can use `itertools.combinations()` to create combinations of the `x, y and z` and plot the data. I have combined both plots into one, which looks better IMO. However, you could separate them if needed.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 10))

food = {"col1": [1, 2], "col2": [3, 4]}
food_df = pd.DataFrame(data=food)

meat = {"col1": [3, 6], "col2": [1, 2]}
meat_df = pd.DataFrame(data=meat)

vege = {"col1": [5, 9], "col2": [0, 3]}
vege_df = pd.DataFrame(data=vege)
# Here is my current codes

kind = ["fooood", "meats", "vegea"]
features = ["Attack", "Volume"]
kind1 = 1
kind2 = 2
col = ["dd", "aa"]


def plot_scatter(feature):
    ind = features.index(feature)
    x = food_df.iloc[ind]
    y = meat_df.iloc[ind]
    z = vege_df.iloc[ind]
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations((x, y, z), 2))

    ax = axes[ind]

    for col1, col2 in combinations:
        for i, c in enumerate(np.unique(col)):
            ax.scatter(col1, col2, c="b")
        for i, txt in enumerate(col):
            ax.annotate(
                txt,
                (col1[i], col2[i]),
                xytext=(col1[i] + 0.0001, col2[i] + 0.0001),
                size=12,
            )

    ax.set_xlabel(kind[kind1], size=15)
    ax.set_ylabel(kind[kind2], size=15)
    ax.set_title(f"{feature}")


plot_scatter("Attack")
plot_scatter("Volume")
plt.show()
fig.savefig("test.png")
```

Result:
[image: resultant plot]

Comment: This is awesome!!! Thanks. By the way, could i plot with plt, not subplots?

Comment: subplots() allows us to control what to plot in each individual plot. If you want to have 3 * 2 = 6 total individual figures, then you could probably use plt. But I wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: Okay! That’s fine. I could just adjust the figsize then the plots won’t be squeezed!